# React-Native iOS App Build Failure - Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: react-native

I am running a react-native app on my local Mac OS X El Capitan machine.  I have installed the required dependencies, but the app is still not launching in iOS simulator.

Here is the output:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app/F8v2 normal x86_64
(1 failure)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
/Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:464:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:484:13)
    at _runIOS (/Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:82:32)
    at /Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (/Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
    at Array.runIOS (/Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:23:10)
    at Object.run (/Users/-/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:96:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean & rebuild your project?
Have you run `cd ios && pod install` and open .xcworkspace file?

Comment: The same issue is discussed here, with multiple different ideas on how to fix: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308 - what worked for me was running `react-native upgrade` to get the latest pbxproject file changes.

Answer (score 16):

Run `react-native upgrade` and overwrite all iOS files. That did it for me.

Comment: the only solution that fixed it out of all of them scattered across the internet

Comment: What if I dont want to change react-native version ? Is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was a space in `build/info.plist`'s directory path.
Removing a space in a parent folder's name solved it.