# react-native CFBundleIdentifier Does Not Exist

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

ten days ago, my react-native project is ok , i do nothing in this project .but now it's error at this. i found some of solution on internet but it can't resolve my question. why it dosen’t work? and i init new project also has error same to this in version 0.45.0  0.45.1  0.46.0  0.46.1 .

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/reactthree.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CF

BundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/reactthree.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Comment: Could you try deleting your ```ios``` folder and then run ```$react-native upgrade``` and ```$react-native link``` commands consecutively.

Comment: thanks for you , i try this commands but also has error of "CFBundleIdentifier "  and you know other solution?

Comment: There are many answers to your question in SO, like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028137/react-native-awesomeproject-react-native-run-ios-build-failed?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133567/provide-a-valid-path-to-the-desired-application-bundle-print-entry-cfbundle?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461703/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist?rq=1), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811292/react-native-ios-app-build-failure-print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-n?rq=1). Last advice of mine is try to be on debug mode rather than release.

Comment: what's mean with debug mode rather than release ?  react-native has release mode ?

Comment: In Xcode you can configure your builds either to be debug or release. And yes, when you bundle your react-native application, you can think of it to be ready for release.